# Помогите. Пишу игру виселицу, и при вводе буквы, встречающейся в слове 2 раза, программа пишет только одну

Tags: python

Например, слово баскетбол, в слове две буквы 'б'. При вводе буквы б, будет так:

> ```
> Б_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
> ```

Вот часть кода:

```
while a!=word:
    letter = input('Ваш выбор: ')
    index = abc.index(letter)
    a[index] = letter
    index = abc.index(letter)
    print(a)
```

Помогите, буду рад любому объяснению.

Comment: Эм. Объясняю: Вы один раз "print" написали, он один раз и исполняется

Answer (score 3):

```
word = "баскетбол"
a = "-" * len(word)

while a != word:
    letter = input('Ваш выбор: ')
    for i, char in enumerate(word):
        if char == letter:
            a = a[:i] + char + a[i+1:]
    print(a)
```

---

*Объяснение:*

- `enumerate(word)` сделает из слова `word`как бы список парей (позиция, буква), в нашем случае такой:

  > ```
  > [(0, 'б'),
  >  (1, 'а'),
  >  (2, 'с'),
  >  (3, 'к'),
  >  (4, 'е'),
  >  (5, 'т'),
  >  (6, 'б'),
  >  (7, 'о'),
  >  (8, 'л')]
  > ```
- в цикле `for i, char in enumerate(word):` будет в переменной `i` текущая *позиция (индекс)* и в переменной `char` соответствующая текущая *буква*,
- когда текущая буква *совпадает* с буквой введенной пользователем, она запишется на текущую позицию, но
- потому что строку *невозможно прямо менять*, строка вырабатывается из части перед индексом, затем следует самая текущая буква и за нее часть после индекса:

  ```
  a = a[:i] + char + a[i+1:]
  ```

Comment: Я добавил эту часть кода, но получается как-то так: Ваш выбор: б б_ б _ _ _ _ и потом когда собрано всё слово получается так: бейсбол_ _ _

Comment: Не добавить, а заменить. Я мой код всегда тестирую, он работает правильно. *«Получается как-то так»* не очень точная формулировка вашей проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том что метод `index` возвращает индекс первого совпадения. В коде ниже этот метод также был заменен на `find`, потому что `index` вызывает ошибку если не находит совпадения в отличии от `find`, который возвращает `-1`. Для того чтобы получить индексы всех букв нужно пройтись по ним циклом, при этом каждый раз рассматривая ту часть слова что идет после предыдущего совпадения. Так как каждый раз мы будем брать кусочек слова меньше к нему нужно будет прибавлять предыдущий индекс чтобы получить необходимый результат.

Вот пример кода:

```py
def gallows(word):
  word = word.lower() # Сводим все к нижнему регистру ради правильного сравнения, что не зависит от регистра

  answer_list = ['_' for i in range(len(word))] # Создаем массив состоящий из _ длинною в слово

  while ''.join(answer_list) != word:
    letter = input('Ваш выбор: ').lower()

    if not letter in word: continue # В случае если буква не в слове прекращаем текущую итерацию

    i = -1 # В цикле будет использовать кусок слова начиная с индекса + 1 так что для того чтобы рассмотреть слово целиком начальный индекс равен -1
    while True:
      i = word[i + 1:].find(letter) + i + 1 # Получаем новый индекс

      answer_list[i] = letter # Заменяем _ на букву

      if i == -1 or not letter in word[i + 1:]: break # Прекращаем цикл вот таким образом для того чтобы произошла хоть одна итерация
    print(' '.join(answer_list))
  print('Вы победили')
```